# What is the best way for Shiny to execute only after multiple individuals submit?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny program that has multiple users. I've coded each user to be in a pair after they log in. They have a value that will be updated when both are ``Ready''

```
Participants[Group] <- list(
    Person1=list(Ready=FALSE, value=0),
    Person2=list(Ready=FALSE, value=0))
```

I want my code to execute only after both members of the pair have submitted their inputs. For example,

### ui.R

```
sliderInput("value",min=1,max=3)
actionButton("enter")
```

### server.R

```
ReactParts <- reactiveValues()
ReactParts$Participants <- Participants

observeEvent( input$enter, {
    if( all( 
        sapply(Participants[Group], function(i){i$Ready == TRUE}) ) )
    {
        ReactParts$Participants[Group]$value <- input$value
    } ## else { do nothing}
})
```

What is the best way to handle inputs conditional on all individuals in the group have clicked `enter`?

Comment: Create an `observer` that queries a database every n seconds after the button has been clicked.

Comment: `reactivePoll` is better than observe for getting the data periodically https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactivePoll.html

Comment: The data are actually being updated in the process and are reactive. I've updated the question.